# How to create a triangular grid using html and css

Tags: html, css, grid

How can I create a grid like the image below? I am trying to make a grid that can be used for my project but I am really unsure of how I should go about this problem.

Can somebody please help me?

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPa7a.png)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  
  <div class="row2">
     <div class="triangle2"></div>
    <div class="triangle3"></div>
    <div class="triangle2"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add more triangles as needed -->
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.triangle2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Not my solution but I found project with explanation which might be helpful:
- Here is CodePen: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/VzBapm/
- Here is a video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej4za1UWhXU
- Here some custom shaping: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-and-custom-shapes-part-1/

Comment: Here is a grid example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRqbovw borders are drawn from the grid background itself. Gap, padding, and spanning grid cells is used aside clip-path.

Answer (score 4):

With `clip-path` you can the create triangles you need and use a negative left and right `margin` to put them side by side.

- triangle pointing up: `clip-path: polygon(50%   0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%)`
- triangle pointing down: `clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0%   0%, 100%   0%)`
- negative margin: -1 x 1/4th of the width of a triangle

Beware: when you need borders, the previously adviced SVG solutions may be a better choice as `clip-path` clips borders as well.

Note: make sure to hover the triangles in the snippet.

```css
/* Grid setup */
.grid    { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; }
.row     { display: flex; justify-content: center; }
.row > * { display: grid; place-items: center }

/* Triangle setup */
.grid { --triangle-size: calc(12.5vw + 1rem); /*  y=mx+b for points p1(160,36) p2(1920,256) */ }

.row > :nth-child(odd)  { clip-path: polygon(50%   0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%); background-color: LemonChiffon } /* up   */
.row > :nth-child(even) { clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0%   0%, 100%   0%); background-color: LightBlue    } /* Down */

.row > * {
    width : var(--triangle-size);
    height: var(--triangle-size);
    margin: 0 calc(-1 * var(--triangle-size)/4);
}

/* Action */
.row > :hover { background-color: tomato }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```